# Ostrstream unpredicted behavior in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl

```
ostrstream  m_msgStream;
m_msgStream.seekp(0);
m_msgStream << "Hello";
m_msgStream << ends;
char *str = m_msgStream .str();
```

We are getting str NULL. If we remove the skeep line then it working fine.  Even the same code is working fine with VS 6. Anyidea how to use seekp in VS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

`ostrstream` is deprecated. Use `std::ostringstream` instead.

```
#include <sstream>
std::ostringstream m_msgStream;
m_msgStream << "Hello";
std::string str = m_msgStream().str();
const char* cstr = str.c_str();
```

Comment: This is basically corret. Just to summarize you must use `m_msgStream.str().c_str()` or else you get a std::string and not a char*.

Comment: m_msgStream().str();
return the char* only.