# ostringstream conversion from VS6 to VS2010

Tags: c++, ostringstream

I have this code that work's well under VS6 but gives me errors in VS2010 :

```
void CGreatString::operator>> (char * lpszDest)
{
strcpy (lpszDest, str());
rdbuf()->freeze(0);
}
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956293/ostrstream-unpredicted-behavior-in-vs-2008) for something similar to my problem, but it still didn't work ...

So from what I have understand, ostrstream is deprecated in VS2010, so I tried this :

```
void CGreatString::operator>> (char * lpszDest)
{
ostringstream os;
string str = os().str();                     //Error 1 and 2
strcpy (lpszDest, str.c_str());
os.rdbuf()->freeze(0);                       //Error 3
}
```

But I still get errors :

1- error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

2- error C2228: left of '.str' must have class/struct/union

3- error C2039: 'freeze' : is not a member of 'std::basic_stringbuf<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `os.str();` since `ostringstream` doesn't have an overloaded `operator()`

Comment: What is *os()*? :) What are you trying to do with freeze function? Streambuf class doesn't have a freeze method - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/.

Comment: True! I only have the freeze problem now!

Comment: The freeze function is to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: @LolCat it doesn't help, just remove it. Also note that your string will be empty since you don't put anything into `os`

Comment: @Seth Ok I'll remove it. From what I see, you are right about the fact that the string will be empty, but I didn't write the vs6 code, so I'll look more into that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin he already did :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yup -- I should have loaded them when it said there were more comments.

Comment: If you could write an answer, it would be nice for other users, since I can't answer my own question yet (not enough reputation)... Thanks you all!

Comment: In the original VS6 code I assume `CGreatString` is derived from `strstream`, so it copies its own data to the destination.  In your "corrected" code you are copying the empty `ostringstream`'s data to the destination, which does nothing.  i.e. you've changed an operation on `*this` to an operation on an empty `ostringstream` so that's clearly not equivalent.  Maybe you want to change `CGreaatString` to derive from a stringstream instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on my questions, I've been able to correct it. Thanks!

```
void CGreatString::operator>> (char * lpszDest)
{
    ostringstream os;
    string str = os.str();
    strcpy (lpszDest, str.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So mini markdown doesn't work in comments. Great, that's just grate.

```
void CGreatString::operator>> (char * lpszDest)
{
    // copy lpszDest into my CGreatString
    // The code you write does nothing at all.
}
```